# Structure of finite pretty ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Since this question [Characteristics of a pretty ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263068/characteristics-of-a-pretty-ring/3263108#3263108) I am interested in "pretty rings".

**Definition:** A *pretty* ring $R$ is a ring with unity 1, not a field, and each nonzero element can be written ***uniquely*** as a sum of a unit and a nonunit element of $R$.

I've already asked a question about the structure of pretty rings (namely here [Characterization of pretty rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264212/characterization-of-pretty-rings)) and realized that my intuition about their structure was not quite right. For instance, we can have noncommutative pretty rings. For example the polynomial ring in two noncommutative variables over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is pretty and noncommutative.

> 1.)  Does there exist a finite pretty ring nonisomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2^{\oplus n}$?

and can we go further and remove commutativity in the finite case?

> 2.) Does there exist a finite noncommutative pretty ring?

I tried to construct a counterexample myself picking a noncommutative monoid and considering $R_S:=\mathbb{F}_2[S]$. This is a noncommutative unital ring (also finite if $S$ is finite). However, I fail to see how to pick the monoid such that $\vert R_S^\times \vert =1$ (which is equivalent to being a pretty ring, see my answer to this question [Characteristics of a pretty ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263068/characteristics-of-a-pretty-ring/3263108#3263108)).

A necessary condition is that $S$ has only one invertible element, but this is not sufficient. Namely, consider $S=\{ 1, a, b\}$ with $1$ being the neutral element and for $x,y \in \{ a, b\}$ we define
$$ x\cdot y := x.$$
Then $R_S$ is noncommutative and unital, but
$$ (1 + a + b)^2 = 1 + 4 a + 4 b =1 $$
and thus $R_S$ is not pretty.

I am aware that that not all pretty rings are isomorphic to some $R_S$ (for example the polynomial ring is not), however, I couldn't come up with a better way of thinking about this problem.

> 3.) Do the pretty rings have a "real" name? Are there people studying them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to 1) is Yes and 2) is No.

Earlier you established they have exactly one unit, and that implies they are reduced. A finite reduced ring is a finite direct product of fields (by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem and Wedderburn's little theorem).

Such a product must be commutative, so this answers 2).

Clearly if any of the fields is something more than $F_2$, you have extra units. So all the fields have to be isomorphic to $F_2$. This answers 1).

3) I've never heard of them. The uniqueness condition is highly restrictive.  TBH I am not sure why one would choose this definition given that "has only one unit" is so much more concise.

A more popular subject of study are [clean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_ring) in which elements are the sum of a unit and idempotent. There is a notion of a [uniquely clean ring](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231892043_Rings_in_which_elements_are_uniquely_the_sum_of_an_idempotent_and_a_unit) which additionally requires uniqueness.

---

*Update*

Just now I ran across a paper defining a generalization of clean rings called [left unit fusible rings](http://home.fau.edu/wmcgove1/web/Papers/Fusible.pdf) which is similar to what you describe with uniqueness dropped, and "nonunit" replaced by "zero divisor."

> Ghashghaei, E., & McGovern, W. W. (2017). Fusible rings. Communications in Algebra, 45(3), 1151-1165.

Comment: Great! Very neat proof. I agree that the definition is nicer stated in the terms of having only one unit, however, I wanted to keep the one in the original question. Thanks for the paper.